# Jquery only Few special character validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

How can I validate all textbox on page with mentioned special characters on key up event using jquery.

Special characters should not allowed are: <>()"'/&

Can I have jquery validation on all textbox with regex?

Please help.

I did in .net with below lines of regex
     Dim StringPattern As String = "[<>()""'\&]"
     Dim RGXSafeString As New Regex(StringPattern)
     IsValidString = Not RGXSafeString.IsMatch(StringValue)

Answer (score 0):

well there is a jQuery plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ you can checkout demos of it over there too.

But since you are familiar with Regular Expression I suggest you to look for JavaScript Regular Expression over http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml **there are couple of more tuts in bottom too.**

Comment: Thanks,But Can I have Regex with validation example?  I tried below regex in javascript but it is not working properly for mentioned special characters      if (StringValue.match(/^[\/<>()'"&]*/) != "")

Comment: Is there any one else which helps me out on regex expression??